# Positioning of grid cells into named areas has

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I want to put some named grid cells into named areas but some of them not positioned correctly as expected.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  cursor: e-resize;
  grid-template-columns: [col-0-start] 277px [col-1-start] 277px [col-2-start] 277px [col-3-start] 277px [col-4-start] 277px [col-5-start];
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: [row-8_00-start] 42px [row-8_00-end row-8_15-start] 42px  [row-8_15-end row-8_30-start] 42px [row-8_30-end row-8_45-start] 42px  [row-8_45-end row-9_00-start] 42px [row-9_00-end row-9_15-start] 42px  [row-9_15-end row-9_30-start] 42px [row-9_30-end row-9_45-start] 42px  [row-9_45-end row-10_00-start] 42px [row-10_00-end row-10_15-start] 42px  [row-10_15-end row-10_30-start] 42px [row-10_30-end row-10_45-start] 42px  [row-10_45-end row-11_00-start] 42px [row-11_00-end row-11_15-start] 42px  [row-11_15-end row-11_30-start] 42px [row-11_30-end row-11_45-start] 42px  [row-11_45-end row-12_00-start] 42px [row-12_00-end row-12_15-start] 42px  [row-12_15-end row-12_30-start] 42px [row-12_30-end row-12_45-start] 42px  [row-12_45-end row-13_00-start] 42px [row-13_00-end row-13_15-start] 42px  [row-13_15-end row-13_30-start] 42px [row-13_30-end row-13_45-start] 42px  [row-13_45-end row-14_00-start] 42px [row-14_00-end row-14_15-start] 42px  [row-14_15-end row-14_30-start] 42px [row-14_30-end row-14_45-start] 42px  [row-14_45-end row-15_00-start] 42px [row-15_00-end row-15_15-start] 42px  [row-15_15-end row-15_30-start] 42px [row-15_30-end row-15_45-start] 42px  [row-15_45-end row-16_00-start] 42px [row-16_00-end row-16_15-start] 42px  [row-16_15-end row-16_30-start] 42px [row-16_30-end row-16_45-start] 42px  [row-16_45-end row-17_00-start] 42px [row-17_00-end row-17_15-start] 42px  [row-17_15-end row-17_30-start] 42px [row-17_30-end row-17_45-start] 42px  [row-17_45-end row-18_00-start] 42px [row-18_00-end row-18_15-start] 42px  [row-18_15-end row-18_30-start] 42px [row-18_30-end row-18_45-start] 42px  [row-18_45-end row-19_00-start] 42px [row-19_00-end row-19_15-start] 42px  [row-19_15-end row-19_30-start] 42px [row-19_30-end row-19_45-start] 42px  [row-19_45-end row-20_00-start] 42px [row-20_00-end row-20_15-start] 42px  [row-20_15-end row-20_30-start] 42px [row-20_30-end row-20_45-start] 42px  [row-20_45-end row-21_00-start] 42px [row-21_00-end row-21_15-start] 42px  [row-21_15-end row-21_30-start row-end];
}

.child {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: row-09_00-start / col-0-start / row-09_30-start / col-1-start;
    /*
    grid-row: row-09_00-start / row-09_30-start;
    grid-column: col-0-start / col-1-start;
    */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #0000;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #4D4D4D;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #d1fee7;
    border: 2px solid #47CD8C;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"><div class="child">Child</div></div>
```

Also, it did not work with `grid-row` and `grid-body`.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-sun-682vpw?file=/index.html) sample

Comment: @Paulie_D It added in codesandbox

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D Codes are presented in the question body! it's so simple code

Comment: You are declaring multiple rows and columns. What is in those?

Comment: Could you say what was not correctly positioned? What result are you expecting compared to what you are getting?

Comment: @AHaworth I want to put the created children that are inside the parent cells. in this example the child element should appear in the first column and the fourth row of the grid parent. but it appeared in the first column and last row which is not correct

Comment: @Paulie_D I described in the top message.  position of the child element is not correct in the grid parent

Comment: Can you point me to a reference for the multi-naming of a grid line? It seems (at least on my Windwos10 Edge) that the second name in the [] is not being picked up. If you use the first name then things work. Multiple naming of grid rows is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

It resolved. the problem was the naming of rows whose numbers lower `10` did not have started with `0` in the event that child has `0` in its row naming.